# Adding Compare-Objects results to difference dataset

Tags: sql-server, powershell, diff

I have two System.Data.DataSet objects that I wish to compare using the Compare-Object Cmdlet. I wish to output a dataset with the columns of the original datasets but with only the differences and an additional column with the SideIndicator values calculated in the Compare-Object cmdlet.

Assuming I have these two CSV's:

```
#C:\test.csv
"firstName","lastName"
"Bruce","Wayne"
"Clark","Kent"

#C:\test2.csv
"firstName","lastName"
"Peter","Parker"
"Clark","Kent"
"Jean","Grey"
```

I would like to use the results of:

```
compare-object (Get-Content C:\test.csv) (Get-Content C:\test2.csv)
```

to populate a dataset formatted as follows:

```
#desiredResult
"firstName","lastName","SideIndicator"
"Peter","Parker","=>"
"Jean","Grey","=>"
"Bruce","Wayne","<="
```

Thanks,
Zach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give `$output` the value you are looking for.

```
$output = Compare-Object $(Import-Csv c:\test.csv) $(Import-Csv c:\test2.csv) -Property FirstName, Lastname
```

When you use `Get-Content` of a file, it puts each line as an object of the array. This treats the `firstname` and `lastname` as a single line, which exists in both arrays. Therefore, it's not returned with the `compare-object` since it is in both.

When you use `Import-Csv` it takes the first row as headers, and makes them properties to the array.  Each line after that is added to the property based on it's location in the `.csv`.  This means that `compare-object` can compare them with different arrays, and maintain the properties to an output.

Comment: No worries, I updated the answer to include why it does that for future readers.